# Why volley android can't load url google maps with device have Api < 21

Tags: android, google-maps

When I used volley to load data in android,I have a trouble.I used volley load googlemaps.
This is url:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=No%204,%20Ng%C3%B5%20151B%20Th%C3%A1i%20H%C3%A0,%20L%C3%A1ng%20H%E1%BA%A1,%20%C4%90%E1%BB%91ng%20%C4%90a,%20H%C3%A0%20N%E1%BB%99i,%20Vietnam

1.In device >5.0.Volley loads it.

2.In device <5.0 like this: AsusZ002-Android:4.4.2,Htc-Android:4.2.2.Volley can't load it.

The bug is:

> "Unexpected response code 400 for [http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=No%204,%20Ngõ%20151B%20Thái%20Hà,%20Láng%20Hạ,%20Đống%20Đa,%20Hà%20Nội,%20Vietnam](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=No%204,%20Ng%C3%B5%20151B%20Th%C3%A1i%20H%C3%A0,%20L%C3%A1ng%20H%E1%BA%A1,%20%C4%90%E1%BB%91ng%20%C4%90a,%20H%C3%A0%20N%E1%BB%99i,%20Vietnam)"

Although a paste in website responses as json success.

Can you answer my questions?Thanks for having look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use URL encoder before loading it like so :

```
String url = http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=No%204,%20Ng%C3%B5%20151B%20Th%C3%A1i%20H%C3%A0,%20L%C3%A1ng%20H%E1%BA%A1,%20%C4%90%E1%BB%91ng%20%C4%90a,%20H%C3%A0%20N%E1%BB%99i,%20Vietnam;
String formattedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
```